# How to calculate percentages considering one variable in first dataframe is an aggregated sum from different values in another data frame

Tags: r

I have a problem with with two data frames when I try to calculate percentages. In the first data frame I have cumulate amounts for different operations that a person makes. These are data frame, the first is the original data frame with information for each person:

```
z=data.frame(ID=c("0001","0002","0002","0001","0003","0003","0004","0004","0001","0003"),Amount=c(10,20,10,30,50,10,40,10,10,30),Place=c("KFC","Marcys","Ezone","Ezone","Italocafe","Italocafe","KFC","Walmart","KFC","KFC"))
```

After when I aggregated I have this:

```
   ID       Final.Amount
1 0001           50
2 0002           30
3 0003           90
4 0004           50
```

I wanto calcule the percentage for each ID related to Place variable, I tried with plyr but I don't get the result. I look for someone like this:

```
 ID     Final.Amount Perct.KFC Perct.Macys Perct.Ezonne Perct.Italocafe Percent.Walmart
1 0001           50       40%         0%          60%           0%              0% 
2 0002           30        0%         67%         33%           0%              0%
3 0003           90       33%         0%           0%           67%             0%
4 0004           50       80%         0%           0%           0%             20%
```

I tried with plyr but I don't get the correct structure, I don't know if I need sqldf or other package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `reshape2` :

```
library(reshape2)
d <- acast(z, ID~Place, value.var="Amount", fun=sum)
prop.table(d,1)*100
```

Which gives :

```
        Ezone Italocafe      KFC   Marcys Walmart
0001 60.00000   0.00000 40.00000  0.00000       0
0002 33.33333   0.00000  0.00000 66.66667       0
0003  0.00000  66.66667 33.33333  0.00000       0
0004  0.00000   0.00000 80.00000  0.00000      20
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rewrite of the answer using `data.table` and base's `reshape`. I have to resort to shaping functions after computing percentages.

```
require(data.table)
w  <- data.table(z)
w1 <- w[, list(val=sum(Amount)), by=list(ID, Place)][, list(Place=Place, 
                       percent=val/sum(val) * 100), by=ID]
reshape(w1, idvar="ID", timevar="Place", direction="wide")

#      ID percent.KFC percent.Ezone percent.Marcys percent.Italocafe percent.Walmart
# 1: 0001    40.00000      60.00000             NA                NA              NA
# 2: 0002          NA      33.33333       66.66667                NA              NA
# 3: 0003    33.33333            NA             NA          66.66667              NA
# 4: 0004    80.00000            NA             NA                NA              20
```